# Progress indicator for async knockout validation?

Tags: ajax, knockout-validation

Has anyone used a progress indicator on an async remote validator using knockout.validation?

I'm doing a jQuery AJAX get to determine if a username is unique, and would like to show a progress indicator or spinner while this is happening.

I'm not sure if this is possible out of the box, but if there is any guidance on how to do this or if anyone has done this already and is willing to share their experience, that would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're in luck. there is an isValidating function that gets attached to observables so you can track when the async rule is running on it.

in your markup, you could then just put some spinner image or whatever like this:

```
<div data-bind="visible: someObservable.isValidating()">
    <img src="spinner.gif"/>
</div>
```

Comment: High five! Thanks for that :) It also works in custom message templates (which I'm using), by using `field.isValidating`